# Converting from lowercase to uppercase using decimal/binary representation of alphabets

Tags: binary, riscv

I'm using RISC-V and I am limited to using just and, or, xori, addition, subtraction, multiplication, division of integer values.

So for instance, the letter "a" will be represented as 97 and "aa" will be represented as 24929, and so on. The UI converts binary sequence into decimal representation, and I cannot directly modify n-th bit.

Is there anyway I can find a simple, general equation of converting from lowercase to uppercase the decimal representation of a maximum of 8 letter sequence of Strings?

Also, I forgot to add, I can't partition the string into individual letters either. Maybe it's possible, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Letters or characters are usually represented as byte values, which are easier to read in hexadecimal. This can be seen if you convert 97 and 24929 to hex.
2. You did not mention the system which was used to encode the characters; mentioning the value for one character is not definitive. Assuming your letters are encoded as ASCII, find an ASCII table and figure out the DIFFERENCE between upper- and lowercase character codes.
3. Use this knowledge to design an algorithm to transform lowercase character codes to uppercase.
4. A good uppercase conversion algorithm will not modify characters that are not lowercase letters.
5. This can be extended to SIMD if you are careful to avoid carries between bytes if you need to add or subtract.